# Read/Write permission are not triggering in android

Tags: android, permissions

Hi in the below code When I am trying click it is showing you don't have read and access permission.But in the manifest file I has given those two permission.Both read and write permission are not triggering with my below code.Both the permission I am calling haspermission evry time failing

Can any one help me where I did the mistake.

java:

```
 private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
String modality_name = opportunity.getModality();
        if (modality_name.equals("LCS")||modality_name.equals("Ultrasound")||modality_name.equals("DI")) {
            // Toast.makeText(mContext, modality_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            holder.pdf.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else {
            holder.pdf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {

                        Log.v(TAG, "download() Method DON'T HAVE PERMISSIONS ");

                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(mContext, "You don't have read access !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t.show();

                    } else {
                        File d = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);  // -> filename = maven.pdf
                        String url_path = opportunity.getPdf_link();
                        ///Log.d("url_path", url_path);
                        String file_name = url_path.substring(url_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        //Log.d("file_name", file_name);
                        File pdfFile = new File(d, file_name);

                        Log.v(TAG, "view() Method pdfFile " + pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        if(pdfFile!=null) {

                            Uri path = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", pdfFile);


                            Log.v(TAG, "view() Method path " + url_path);

                            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                            try {
                                mContext.startActivity(pdfIntent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            //  }
                        }
                        Log.v(TAG, "view() Method completed ");
                        // download(v);
                        //request(v);
                    }
                    download(v);
                    // request(v);


                }


                public void request(View v) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, 112);

                }

                public void download(View v) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "download() Method invoked ");

                    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {

                        Log.v(TAG, "download() Method DON'T HAVE PERMISSIONS ");

                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(mContext, "You don't have write access !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t.show();

                    } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "download() Method HAVE PERMISSIONS ");
                        String url_path = opportunity.getPdf_link();
                        Log.d("url_path", url_path);
                        String file_name = url_path.substring(url_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        Log.d("file_name", file_name);

                        new DownloadFile().execute(url_path, file_name);

                    }

                    Log.v(TAG, "download() Method completed ");

                }


            });
        }


    }


//    public DragListener getDragInstance() {
//        if (mlistener != null) {
//            return new DragListener(mlistener);
//        } else {
//            Log.e("Route Adapter: ", "Initialize listener first!");
//            return null;
//        }
//    }
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() Method invoked ");
            String fileUrl = strings[0];
            Log.d("fileurl",fileUrl);

            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
            Log.d("fileName",fileName);
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() pdfFile invoked " + pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() pdfFile invoked " + pdfFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            try {
                pdfFile.createNewFile();
                Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() file created" + pdfFile);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() error" + e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() error" + e.getStackTrace());


            }
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() file download completed");

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, **WRITE** permission grants you both READ/WRITE access, so you don't need to send a request for both
2. Check if permission is granted by this method, no need for all of those API checks:

```
private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

If permission is not granted first before everything else just request the permission:

```
requestPermissions(new String[Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], 123);
```

Check if permission is granted and then continue your work:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 123 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Do your work
    }
    else {
        //Permission is not granted do what you want
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

---

In your code:

inside `holder.pdf.setOnClickListener()'s onCLick()`

```
if (!isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
    requestPermissions(new String[Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], 123);
} else {
    //Do your job
}
```

Comment: @jyosrijyo Change it with boolean my mistake. I also edited my answer. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: isPermissionGranted where you calling

Comment: @jyosrijyo call `isPermissionGranted` when you want to perform the action that is going to need permission. Check that inside an `if` statement.

Comment: requestPermissions(new String[Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], 123); giving me anerror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214677/discussion-between-jyo-srijyo-and-abstractarrow).

Comment: `String permission` can not reach inside the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)`. Android studio marks it as unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

use this for android 13 and higher

```
     - READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
     - READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
     - READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE seems to be not work in android 13

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions